# Why is Torque changing the name of my output files?

Tags: pbs

I have a line in the script I submit to torque that looks like this:

```
#PBS -o /path/to/output/file/directory/file_name_with_some_underscores.out
```

But when I look for this output file, it's called something like this:

```
/path/to/output/file/directory/file_name_with_some_underscores.o36091
```

Where 36091 is the job ID number.  I have multiple jobs running simultaneously with the same output file, but I've done that before and this has never happened previously.

Why is Torque doing this?

Comment: @woodchips: There was a [meta post](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/152/are-tool-questions-on-topic-here) discussing this a while back. Questions about tools are considered on-topic.

Comment: When you say that you've done "this" before, was it on the exact same machine?

Comment: @Paul: Yes. Everything that struck me as at all relevant was exactly the same, though I'm unsure if TORQUE was updated.

Answer (score 2):

do you happen to have any non-comment lines in your batch script before the #PBS -o line?  TORQUE will ignore any #PBS lines that occur after the first executable statement in the script.  The qsub command will scan your batch script for #PBS lines until it encounters a line that is not a comment or whitespace.